# Why am I failing to programmatically create a webform in hook_entity_insert?

Tags: 8, webforms

I need to create a webform programmatically when a node is created.
I refer and follow https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3038697

Here are the steps to reproduce:

1. Create new module via console, and install module.
2. In module.module add:

   ```php
   use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface; 
   use Drupal\Core\Serialization\Yaml;
   use Drupal\webform\Entity\Webform;
   ```

   Add hook with webform create function:

   ```php
   function module_entity_insert(EntityInterface $entity){
     // Build a render array of elements.
     $elements = [
       'name' => [
         '#type' => 'textfield',
         '#title' => t('Name'),
       ],
     ];

     $settings = [
       // Define settings.
     ];

     // Append default settings.
     $settings += Webform::getDefaultSettings();

     // Create a webform.
     $webform = Webform::create([
       'id' => 'custom_id',
       'title' => 'Title',
       'elements' => Yaml::encode($elements),
       'settings' => $settings,
     ]);

     $webform->save();
   }
   ```
3. Now, after save and cache clear, go to add new content (any type will do).

   Suppose I have new sample webform created along the new node creation, but here is the error message:

   > The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Object support when dumping a YAML file has been disabled. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 847 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

Drupal version is latest, fresh install. What am I doing wrong? Or what's missing?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was at line:

```php
'elements' => Yaml::encode($elements)
```

The solution is to replace the `Yaml` in the `use` statement:

from:

```php
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Yaml;
```

to:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
```

I don't know the exact explanation, it just works on my code.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this error...just change t('Name') to 'Name' and it should work.

Apparently the translate function expands out to an object (instead of what you might expect...'Name' or 'Nombre'...etc): and dumping objects to yaml is apparently no longer "allowed".

Ex:

```
Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup Object
(
    [translatedMarkup:protected] =>
    [options:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [stringTranslation:protected] =>
    [string:protected] => Name
    [arguments:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: There is a `render()` method on `TranslatableMarkup` that returns a string...I wonder if using `t('name')->render()` might do the trick, although I'd never think that'd be the way to handle this. It probably won't work but may be worth a shot

Comment: I tried adding ->render() on the t() function calls and it worked great, no more error. Thanks